# How to Keep the date Format in a Particular Formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to Keep the date Format in a Particular Formula ?

Exemple :

[image]

NB : I Use French Excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could format the date as text in your formula:

`=E5&":"&TEXT(F5,"DD/MM/YYYY")`

edit: And of course, hypothetically speaking, if you were in France:

`=E5&":"&TEXTE(F5;"JJ/MM/AAAA")`

Comment: Ha, you beat me to the punch by a few seconds!

Comment: thank's for all ,in french is like that : `=E5&":"&TEXTE(F5;"JJ/MM/AAAA")`

Comment: Ah, didn't think about localisation. Glad we could help

Comment: You can accept either to be fair, they're both identical

Comment: @AranDG True, I just said yours because you posted it first.

Comment: I voted for both of the answer's, and accept the old one ,@AranDG you can edit your  answer , add formula for french version

Answer (score 3):

```
= E5&":"&TEXT(F5,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```